What is the recommended approach for testing code handling private keys?
I am implementing a REST API in Go for a web3 client that performs authentication by validating a private key signature. Is there some way I can generate fake but valid private/public key pairs for injecting into test methods?

Any 32 random bytes can be an ed25519 secret key, so feel free to just generate 32 random bytes and create a keypair from that!
